# Using gzcompress in PHP; need to be able to uncompress on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, gzip

I'm sure this isn't too difficult (and I'm surprised I can't figure it out), but here goes:

So. I'm using gzcompress() to compress JSON data in PHP so I can send it into an iPhone app.

Having some troubles figuring out how to uncompress this data on the iPhone (iOS).

Any thoughts? I'm grabbing the data via a NSMutableURLRequest.

Thanks!

---

Code making the request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Code processing the response:

```
NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

And on the PHP side:

```
echo(gzcompress(json_encode($lines)));
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you include some code in your question?

Comment: Add `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` to the top of your php file.  This will gzip all of the data that your php script "sends".  When you get it with the URL request, it should be seamlessly decoded.

Comment: alexy13 -- yeah, I think that did it. I removed the gzcompress() from the PHP and added your line and it seems to have sped up the transfer about 10x. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.bigevilempire.com/codelog/entry/nsurlconnection-with-gzip/) suggests that NSMutableURLRequest supports gzip decompression out-of-the-box, but you need to add an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header to the request.

Extending your example:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL]];
[request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I'd also recommend testing the PHP script with cURL to make sure it's sending valid gzipped data.